# Is is possible to use an app pass the Downtime in Google Family Link?

Tags: google-family-link

**EDIT**: After contact with the Google Family Link support it was revealed that the below is an effect of misunderstanding. There is no bug at all. **Kid has secretly gained access to my phone** and has used *Parental Access* code on her own phone to rule down all the limitations until midnight.

<sub>Keeping for future reference. Feel free to close or delete , if you find it having no actual value for the community.</sub>

<s>Yesterday (today?) I have caught my 14-years old daughter listening to Spotify at 00:30 AM. This is something that per my knowledge is impossible :)</s>

We are using Google Family Link and even though both Spotify app and Google Chrome are set to be used without any limitations:

As the screenshot above shows, pass the Downtime using it should be impossible. And the Downtime is set at 11:30 PM, so an hour and a half before she was still using Spotify:

Please, help me understand what could or what has happened in here.

1. Did the fourteen years old girl truly brought down *the greatest* Google Family Link system?
2. Is this some kind of bug in Family Link and this situation should not happen in your opinion?
3. Or is there something else (maybe blatantly obvious) that I don't understand in this picture?

Comment: @beeshyams Thank you. Report sent to Google, linked issue upvoted. I don't quite get your question. What do you mean by 13? An hour (1 AM) or kid's age? You can use Google Family Link with kids any age and you can apply time restrictions to any hour.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: After contact with the Google Family Link support it was revealed that the below is an effect of misunderstanding. There is no bug at all. **Kid has secretly gained access to my phone** and has used *Parental Access* code on her own phone to rule down all the limitations until midnight.

<sub>Keeping for future reference. Feel free to close or delete , if you find it having no actual value for the community.</sub>

<s>As per information provided by *beeshyams* in comments, this is [most likely a bug](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/209844350/family-link-my-child%E2%80%99s-daily-limit-and-downtime-gets-cancelled?hl=en).</s>

> Greetings! You have a fundamental bug in Family Link that denies usage of this system. Kids are able to use applications pass the Downtime:
>
> https://support.google.com/mail/thread/209844350/family-link-my-child%E2%80%99s-daily-limit-and-downtime-gets-cancelled?hl=en
>
> [Is is possible to use an app pass the Downtime in Google Family Link?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252069/20449)
>
> Is this recorded in your internal bug system? Are works on this in progress. Otherwise we must switch to another solution ASAP because yours isn't working anymore.

This was already reported to Google Family Link support team (with the above text, hence the circular reference to the very same question).